# Regular expression syntax for hours

Tags: php, regex, hour

I need a regular expression for hours in PHP, I am using ereg. I need it to accept 1-23 without leading zeros.

```
^([1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-3])$
```

That's what I am using but I cannot find where is the mistake.

Comment: You'll want to use `preg` instead of `ereg`.  `ereg` says "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternations (`|`) apply to everything in the surrounding group or globally if not in a group. So in your pattern, the `^` only applies to the first pattern and the `$` only applies to the last pattern. In other words, your pattern matches any string which begins with a digit from 1 to 9, contains a 1 followed by a digit from 0 to 9, or ends with a 2 followed by a digit from 0 to 3.

Try putting the different options in one group:

```
^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$
```

Also note, [24-hour time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) starts at 00:00, so your pattern should look more like this:

```
^(1?[0-9]|2[0-3])$
```

Or this, if you need the hour to be 2 digits:

```
^([01][0-9]|2[0-3])$
```

Comment: Thanks. Again when something goes wrong just use brackets everywhere you can.

Comment: @user3319891 Well, no that *can* cause more problems. Just remember to use them in the right way :p