# PHP replace expression in string

Tags: php

I was trying to get this solved in PHP by my self but I had no luck yet.
I have strings like these:

"hello I am a test 12:30 and bla bla bla"
"11:54"
"hello I am a test 23:00"
"00:10 and this is another text"

And I would like to replace this part of the text HH:MM with this text: "new", so the result should be:
"hello I am a test new and bla bla bla"
"new"
"hello I am a test new"
"new and this is another text"

And also get all the extracted texts in an array, like this:
"hello I am a test 12:30 and bla bla bla"
result=[12:30]
"11:54"
result=[11:54]
"hello I am a test 23:00"
result=[23:00]
"00:10 and this is another text"
result=[00:10]
"hello I am a test 23:00 and there is one more 07:55"
result=[23:00,07:55]

NOTE: the string can contains more than one HH:MM, for example:
"hello I am a test 23:00 and there is one more 07:55"

I prefer not use regular expressions.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression syntax for hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256002/regular-expression-syntax-for-hours)

Comment: _"I prefer not use regular expressions"_ - why? (Considering those are probably the best tool for your job.)

Comment: It is because I can't see what the reg expression is doing, plain php code is easy to understand line by line, anyway I am open to use it, "I just don't prefer to use it". If you have a solution using reg exp please show it, it will be very welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Sites like this are really helpful when learning regular expressions. https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks @PavelJanicek but that answer is for "1-23 without leading zeros." which is not my case, my case is HH:MM

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/[\d]{0,2}:[\d]{0,2}/',"new","hello I am a test 12:30 and bla bla bla"));
```

Comment: Fewer characters `\d\d:\d\d`

Comment: thanks Dilraj but is there a way to extract the value HH:MM? I mean extract an array with all the values found, like  12:30, 23:00, etc

Comment: Hi Fernando, you can use preg_match_all method for example

var_dump(preg_match_all('/[\d]{0,2}:[\d]{0,2}/',"hello I am a test 12:30 and bla 01:02 bla bla",$matches),$matches);

Comment: Thank you Diraj! very good an elegant solution! Anyway I would like to use the other solution without regular expression, but that is just my personal choice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use regex... but...i'm not sure that plain php it's more easy to understan or mantain. Indeed you should avoid this:

```
    <?php

/*
   Since the couple HH:MM have a fixed pattern and a fixed length
   search for it in the string and replace each occurrence of them with the @repl 
   you desire.
   NOTE: Each block (HH:MM) Have total length of five char.
   @str : The string on which perform the search.
   @repl : The replacement string
   @return : A new string with each HH:MM occurrence replaced with
    the values of the@repl param
 */
function findEachHM($str, $repl) {
    $refined_str = "";
    $lo = 0; # Last occurrence of the delimiter
    $li = 0; # Last portion taken of the main string
    $delim = ":";

    while (strpos($str, $delim, $lo)) {
        # Take the whole block
        $lo = strpos($str, $delim, $lo) + 3;
        # take the pieces of string that goes from the last occurence of delim to another
        $pieces = substr($str, $li, $lo);
        # doing the replace
        $refined_str .= str_replace(substr($pieces, strlen($pieces) - 5), $repl, $pieces);
        $li = $lo;
    }
    return $refined_str;
}

$str = "hello I am a test 23:00 and there is one more 07:55";
$repl = "new";
$rs = findEachHM($str, $repl);
echo $rs . "\n";
?>
```

This should work for multiple hour:

```php
function findEachHM($str, $repl) {
    $refined_str = array();
    $lo = 0; # Last occurrence of the delimiter
    $li = 0; # Last portion taken of the main string
    $delim = ":";
    $all_delim = array();

    while(strpos($str, $delim, $lo)){
      $lo = strpos($str, $delim, $lo)+1;
      array_push($all_delim, $lo);
    }

    foreach($all_delim as $k=>$pos){
      $pieces = substr($str, $li, (($pos-$li)+2));
      array_push($refined_str, str_replace(substr($pieces, strlen($pieces)-5), $repl, $pieces));
      $li = $pos+2;
    }

    return implode("", $refined_str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mondo, seems to be pretty good! Can we get an array with all the extracted HH:MM ? Like this:  result=[23:00,07:55]

Comment: $pieces hold it. So substr($pieces, strlen($pieces)-5) shold contain it. NOTE: I didnt test that.

Comment: Thanks @Mondo it is working great! Just FYI this script only support 2 expressions maximum, for example this is not supported: "hello 14:30 I am a test 23:00 and there is one more 07:55". Thank you!!!